# Check for balanced parentheses

Tags: java, algorithm, strings, stack

> Given an expression string exp, write a program to examine whether the
>   pairs and the orders of
>
> ```
> "{","}","(",")","[","]"
> ```
>
> are correct in exp.
>
> For example, the program should print true for
>
> ```
> exp = "[()]{}{[()()]()}"
> ```
>
> and false for
>
> ```
> exp = "[(])"
> ```

Complexity:

- Time complexity: O(n) where n is length of the string
- Space complexity: O(n/2) where n is length of string

Looking for code review, optimizations and best practices.

```
public final class BalancedParanthesis {

    private static final Map<Character, Character> brackets = new HashMap<Character, Character>();
    static {
        brackets.put('[', ']');
        brackets.put('{', '}');
        brackets.put('(', ')');
    }  

    private BalancedParanthesis() {};

    /**
     * Returns true is parenthesis match open and close.
     * Understands [], {}, () as the brackets
     * It is clients responsibility to include only valid paranthesis as input.
     * A false could indicate that either parenthesis did not match or input including chars other than valid paranthesis
     * 
     * @param str   the input brackets
     * @return      true if paranthesis match.
     */
    public static boolean isBalanced(String str) {
        if (str.length() == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("String length should be greater than 0");
        }
        // odd number would always result in false
        if ((str.length() % 2) != 0) {
            return false;
        }

        final Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (brackets.containsKey(str.charAt(i))) {
                stack.push(str.charAt(i));
            } else if (stack.empty() || (str.charAt(i) != brackets.get(stack.pop()))) {
                return false;
            } 
        }
        return true;
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        assertEquals(true, isBalanced("{}([])"));
        assertEquals(false,isBalanced("([}])"));
        assertEquals(true, isBalanced("([])"));
        assertEquals(true, isBalanced("()[]{}[][]"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Best practices: 1) Use Snobol (in which most of the program reduces to `BAL x`, where `x` is the string to check for balance).

Comment: Does your code return `false` for `"[(])"` ?

Comment: @konijn Yes, it does.

Comment: Why wouldn't an empty string be trivially balanced?

Comment: I dont know why nobody pointed out but this will fail for input
(A+B)+(C-D)

Comment: Typo: it's one _parenthesis_, two or more _parentheses_, but never _paranthesis_.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I just wanted to write that the code looks completely fine to me, until...

```
assertEquals(false, isBalanced("[["));
```

I''m sure you'll find the error :-)

Otherwise two small remarks:

- Personally I'd have the function return `true` for an empty string instead of throwing an exception.
- `Stack` is outdated. I'd use a [`Deque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) implementation instead.

EDIT: I'm sorry, but I just realized something else: Your program doesn't fulfill the requirement O(n/2) for space complexity.

Comment: Yes it does. O(n/2) is the same as O(n). Whether it's what the instructor intended is a different question...

Comment: Ah, ok. The O notation isn't my strong suit. But you can modify the code so that it only needs to store n/2+1 chars max.

Comment: @fgrieu: Sorry, it will assert. When calling `isBalanced("[[")`, then the two brackets (`[`) will only pushed on to the stack. The second clause of the `if` statement in the `for` loop (and thus the `pop()`s) are never called, so that it reaches the final `return true`. See http://ideone.com/Ed5eiU (doesn't use assert, but outputs `true` to stdout).

Comment: @RoToRa: I stand corrected.

Comment: return stack.isEmpty()

Answer (score 13):

**assertEquals vs assertTrue**

I see that you're using :

> ```
>     assertEquals(true, isBalanced("{}([])"));
>     assertEquals(false,isBalanced("([}])"));
>     assertEquals(true, isBalanced("([])"));
>     assertEquals(true, isBalanced("()[]{}[][]"));
> ```

This is not the best way to assert boolean values. You should be using :

```
    assertTrue(isBalanced("{}([])"));
    assertFalse(isBalanced("([}])"));
    assertTrue(isBalanced("([])"));
    assertTrue(isBalanced("()[]{}[][]"));
```

This is more clear since it is clear that you are checking for true/false.

**Separation**

All your tests are still in the main, I will again strongly recommend to extract those tests in a test class, and create a single method for each case. This will help if you give relevant name to your tests to see at first glance what are you testing specifically. Is it an exception, a normal case, etc.

Answer (score 12):

This code is basically perfect (save for [that little bug found by RoToRa](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/45926/21609)):

- Map initialization in a static initializer block
- constructor is made inaccessible
- the code does what the documentation says
- clever short circuiting
- implementation using explicit stack

However, there are a few points which we can talk about:

- The JavaDoc doesn't mention that the string must contain at least two characters. I would expect that the string `""` is indeed balanced. For me, a balanced string would be described by the following EBNF grammar:

  ```
  <Balanced> ::=
    '(' <Balanced> ')'
  | '{' <Balanced> '}'
  | '[' <Balanced> ']'
  | epsilon
  ```

  that is, the empty string is allowed via this recursive definition. Instead, you've implemented a recognizer for the following grammar:

  ```
  <Balanced> ::=
    '(' <InnerBalanced> ')'
  | '{' <InnerBalanced> '}'
  | '[' <InnerBalanced> ']'

  <InnerBalanced> ::=
    <Balanced>
  | epsilon
  ```
- You forgot to test that `str != null`
- You could use the diamond operator to invoke inference on generic arguments:

  - `Map<Character, Character> brackets = new HashMap<>()`
  - `Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>()`
- A user of your function can't specify custom parens like `<…>`. It would be good to enable some possibility of customization, and default to `(…)` otherwise.
- If you enable custom parens, then there may be some ambiguity – each opening paren would be associated with a set of possible closing parens. Note that given an *O(1)* membership test, this won't affect the algorithmic complexity of your code. Examples: `|…|` (norm operator/`abs` from mathematics), `|…>` (Bra-ket notation from quantum physics), `<…>` (mean value/expected value from statistics).
- When checking whether a given string has balanced parens, this string will usually contain non-paren text as well. A function that returns true for `q{foo($bar{baz} .= do {my $x = '('; bless \$x})}` given the delimiters `{…}` would be useful in real-world applications. Unfortunately, this disables your check that the string must be of even length.
- You only support single “characters” as delimiters. It would be more flexible to allow arbitrary strings. Note that Java's `Character`s aren't real Unicode characters, but effectively only 16-bit code units. To represent any Unicode code point, we need one or two Java characters (think: “`int` is the new `char`”). Note further that this is only sufficient for single code points, whereas one logical character (“grapheme”) may consist of multiple code points.

Comment: "It would be more flexible to allow arbitrary strings" But then the problem gets much harder due to possible overlaps. The same problem occurs if you allow custom single-char brackets and a closing bracket coincides with an opening one. Also why would one need to check for `null` explicitly? The documentation doesn't state that null is a valid input, and by default I would not assume it to be, so is a NullPointerException not enough?

Comment: @NiklasB. An explicit NPE with custom error message makes it much easier for a caller to debug. Leaving behaviour unspecified is a cheap cop out. Also, defensive programming is a best practice. Re ambiguity: this is no problem even with the given algorithmic complexity constraints as long as one sets up a few rules that decide how the input is parsed: e.g. overlapping tokens become a non-issue with longest token matching, committing instead of backtracking preserves _O(n)_ behaviour, and we could decide that closing braces are preferred over opening braces. Further questions? :)

Comment: Sure, you can specify greedy parsing, but that might go against the intuition of users who would assume that the parser just implements the straightforward context-free grammer given in your answer (which would then be hard to parse). Just wanted to point out that if you go that road you will need to consider a lot of details. W.r.t defensive, would it be just as acceptable to just say "`null` is never a valid input unless otherwise specified"? That's usually how I do it (for an entire library, not just for certain methods) and it does not leave anything unspecified

Comment: @NiklasB. Yes of course, and I only added suggestions on how to make the `isBalanced` more general. I believe that offering more power to “the user” is preferable to offering a restricted “safe” set of operations, even though more power means that more stuff can go wrong. (For some unfathomable reason, I prefer Perl over Python and Scala over Java…) Oh, I forgot to mention another good way to deal with ambiguity etc.: Just throw an exception when ambiguity is encountered (possibly as early as collecting all braces in a data structure).

Answer (score 7):

The class is misnamed: `BalancedParanthesis` should be `BalancedParentheses`.  "Paranthesis" should be spelled "Parenthesis", and should be made plural to "Parentheses", since you can't balance one parenthesis.

Consider renaming it to `BalancedDelimiters` to be more general, since you support more than just parentheses.

Answer (score 5):

I've only one addition to the other answers

For the stack you use `java.util.Stack`, this seems like an obvious choice, yet it is a remnant from pre-collection times, and is a subclass of `java.util.Vector`, and therefore `synchronized`. You don't need the synchronization overhead, and are better off using `java.util.ArrayDeque`. That is a double ended queue, but functions perfectly as a stack if only accessed from the top. In fact [`Stack`'s javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) advises you to use `ArrayDeque` instead.

Comment: Wouldn't a `LinkedList` be more appropriate? A linked list is optimised for push and pop operations, which is what is used here.

Comment: `ArrayDeque`'s push and pop operations, merely change an int index, only when the array needs to grow, there will be a need to do `System.arrayCopy()`, `LinkedList` will have to create a new `Node` on each push. Since we know the exact maximum needed capacity, we can make sure the `ArrayDeque` never needs to grow, eliminating the one disadvantage for `ArrayDeque`. Even if we don't set a capacity, I think `ArrayDeque` will outperform `LinkedList` in this algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

Even though your `brackets`is private, it is a good practice to make these kind of key-value holders immutable as well. So your code

```
private static final Map<Character, Character> brackets = new HashMap<Character, Character>();
    static {
        brackets.put('[', ']');
        brackets.put('{', '}');
        brackets.put('(', ')');
    }
```

could be rewritten as

```
private static final Map<Character, Character> brackets = Collections.unmodifiableMap(new HashMap<Character, Character>() {{
        put('[', ']');
        put('{', '}');
        put('(', ')');
    }});
```

This is more concise and also serves as good documentation even if your `Map` is `private` and even if you don't have a setter.

Another way is to use [Guava library](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/GuavaExplained) from Google which claims better performance and real immutability with a more concise syntax

```
private static final Map<Character, Character> guavaBracket = ImmutableMap.of('[', ']','{', '}','(', ')');
```

Comment: The instance initializer block you recommend leads to much confusion in real life, especially when you break the Java Code Style guidelines in the way that you have.

Comment: yeah..only if immutability is bad and more verbose code is less confusing in "real life".

Comment: The immutability is fine, but the *anonymous subclass with instance initializer block with non-standard code formatting* is what is confusing... which is what my first comment said. More verbose code or correctly formatted readable code.... call it what you want, but what you are recommending is not best practice in any common reference.

Comment: You seem to agree about immutability, I do not know whether any best practice recommendation exists for/against anonymous subclassing in such cases. In production code I had reviewed, I have also seen mostly the approach without anon. subclass which you seem to prefer. But lately I have seen the approach I proposed in use increasingly, especially by those who have coded in non Java languages. Code review in general involves some subjective opinion, sometimes matters of preference, style etc.

Comment: At minimum, [the 'opening' `{{` of the code should be separated by newline](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html), and correctly indented. The closing `}}` should be split as well. The inner `{}` are a code block, and should be on their own lines just like a method block or any other compound statement....

Answer (score 4):

Some remarks:

1. As correctly pointed in the [accepted answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/45926/37580), the code is plain broken; changing `return true` into `return stack.empty()` seems to fix that (disclaimer: I did not run the code).
2. I'm not sure that `stack.push` is truly of complexity O(1), which is necessary to match the "Time complexity: O(n)" requirement (think of what happens for an input consisting of a large even number of `'{'`:  the stack is grown at every push). For this reason I would use, rather than a `stack` object, a single auxiliary <strike>string</strike> `char[]` array of size `str.length()/2` used as a stack, and an index into that. It is enough for the job, tends to make the code much simpler, and makes it appreciably faster (especially since `stack` is `synchronized`, as I learned from [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/45962/37580)).
3. The fragment `for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)` matches the "Time complexity: O(n)" requirement, but its straight C equivalent would squarely not, for there `strlen()` is O(n), thus the statement O(n<sup>2</sup>). I suggest a variable `n` set to `str.length()` on entry, that will likely speed up things slightly, clarify and slightly shorten the code, and in any case can't harm much.
4. My reading of the problem's statement is that the *empty* string is perfectly acceptable.
5. It is not clear from the problem's statement that any character other than the 6 ones in `{}[]()` is prohibited, in particular space.
6. After that change of 1., the test `(str.length() % 2) != 0` becomes redundant, and I would say unwanted (independently of the previous item).
7. I do *not* think that it is useful to add a test that `str` is `null`, for in that case `str.length` will throw an exception, and that's fine for me. It would be good style in C, though.

Comment: 1) Good point that `Stack.push()` could take longer than O(1) time. It may be prudent to call [`Stack.ensureCapacity()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#ensureCapacity\(int\)) to avoid any possible penalty of having to expand the stack. You could also use a `char[]` array. Strings are immutable in Java, though, and would not be suitable.

Comment: @200_success: very right! Fixed it. You guessed it, I'm not truly a Java programmer (I mostly use the Java Card 2 dialect, used in Smart Cards, in the variant where no variable can be `int`, we have only `short`)

Comment: I would object to the test of the `null` string, since if you know that you will be throwing a `NullPointerException` than make a test that expect an exception. If for any reason something change and the exception is not throw anymore you will know it!